# Match pattern in string

Tags: javascript, string, function

I think the issue is that whatever value I have it will always end up being true. If someone could help explain it to me with simple JavaScript for a beginner

```js
function match(string, pattern) {
  var i;
  var letterFound = true;
  var str = string.length;
  if (string.indexOf(pattern) != -1)

  {
    letterFound = true;
  } else letterFound = false;

  return letterFound;
}

alert(match("abcdef", "@C2D!"));
alert(match("abcdef", "CAfe"));
alert(match("abcdef", "CG"));
```

Comment: It isn't Java code

Comment: nor is it related to the tag design-patterns

Comment: this looks like `javascript`

Comment: I modified the tags.

Comment: What is `pattern`?

Comment: pattern is just what I'm using in an alert box to match certain letters in a string.

Comment: Not certain what issue is with code at Question?

Comment: can you give us an example of input to the function?

Comment: I've updated it to show the inputs and how I'm not receiving the expected value of true, true, false.

Comment: Why should it be true, true, false?

Comment: Because its meant to return true if all letters of pattern appear in string

Comment: But they aren't!

Comment: For the first one, C and D are in the string. It's only letters. Unless its meant to be case insensitive?

Comment: But then the last one should also be true!?

Comment: It has to be that all letters of a pattern appear in a string. G isn't in the string in the last one so would be false.

Comment: Letters. Not symbols. C and D are in the pattern and string, therefore it should be true.

Answer (score 0):

1. *Delete* all chars that are not letters with `replace(/[^[A-Za-z]]/g, "")`
2. Make array with [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
3. Go through the array with [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
4. Check if every letter (case insensitive) is in the string with [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes). Return bools.
5. If every bool is true, return true, else return false. ( [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) )

```js
function match(string, pattern) {
  return pattern.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, "").split("").map(ch => {
    return string.includes(ch.toLowerCase());
  }).every(bool => bool === true) ? true : false;
}

console.log(match("abcdef", "@C2D!"));
console.log(match("abcdef", "CAfe"));
console.log(match("abcdef", "CG"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through each character, you can use:
`string.indexOf(pattern);`
Which checks if string contains pattern in one go.

Comment: I tried that, still hasn't worked. I've updated the code for reference. Thanks you.